# How to get data using Like Operator

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to get data from my Access database using like operator. For example my ProducID contains NoteBook, Notes etc. Using like operator, I want to get them all shown if user types No etc.
Like operator did not give any errors but it only shows record when I put full NoteBook (does not show for Notes offcourse)

Please note I want to use the query in dataset (as shown in the pic)

Please advise how to fix it.
Thanks[image]

Comment: What is the data type of ProductCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard is % or *, depending on what you are using to connect, in this case I suggest:

```
SELECT ... FROM Table WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%'
```

Regardless of the data type.

Answer (score 1):

When you passed in the string "No" did you add the wildcard *No* before and after it to ensure it would return items with no anywhere in the string?

If you only want everything after "No" then you would want "No*".

Comment: I put it like Where Product Like '?*' it did not return any errors, but did not show any data as well.